# git artifacts not downloaded included on build agent when using yml and service connecetion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Git repo is not downloaded to agent to reference in next steps in yml
(works in UI).

When I run the build using UI and select the source folder as my git repo I can successfully run build, if I try using yml it only downloads the repo where the yml is contained. I cannot seem to reference the external repo like I do in the UI.

```
pr: none
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Terraform_Repo
    type: github
    name: My-Repo/terraform
    endpoint: My-Repo (service connection)

jobs:
- job: 'azure_buildserver'
  displayName: 'Build Server'
  timeoutInMinutes: 180

  variables:
  - group: ENVBase
  pool:
    name: 'Hosted VS2017'

  steps:

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files to: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
      contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Terraform_Repo'
    inputs:
      ArtifactName: 'Terraform_Repo'here
```

Expect the artifact to be downloaded from the repo specified.

Comment: I think maybe how the source folder is referenced . - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files to: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
      contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, yaml builds should be in the repository that you want to get.

The `resoucres` section in the yaml is not to get the second repo during the build, it's for get a [yaml template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#using-other-repositories) from the second repo.

So, the best practice is to put the yaml in the repository you need, if you don't want you can add a command line step that perform `git clone` of the second repo.

Comment: this is what I ended up implementing